# Hide source block (but not result) in org-tree-slide presentation mode

Tags: org-mode

I'm using `org-tree-slide` for simple presentations. I'm using source code blocks in the following way:

```
#+begin_src python
....
 some code here.... 
....
#+end_src
```

*C-c C-c to evaluate*

```
#+RESULTS:
 result here
```

I wonder if it's possible to hide the source blocks in presentation mode and only display the result of the computation.

If this can't be done with the org-tree-slide package, is there another tool that does it?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know anything about `org-tree-slide`: how about adding a link to the sources? If it works by exporting the document to e.g HTML, then you can use the header `:exports results` to omit the code.

Comment: Have you tried [ox-reveal](https://github.com/hexmode/ox-reveal)? That uses the exporter so the header in the previous comment should work.

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with reveal, but I was specifically looking to do this within emacs, without exporting to html.

Comment: You'll probably need to post your question on the `org-tree-slide` website. I suspect there aren't many people around here with either the interest or the knowledge to answer the question. If you do get a resolution, you might want to come back here and post an answer to your own question.